# java command to call a getconnection method from one class to another

Tags: java, database, h2

```
 public class A {


    // method to get connection
    ComboPooledDataSource cpDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

    public Connection getconnection() throws Exception {

        Connection con = null;
        try {
            // open a connection
            con = cpDataSource.getConnection();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return con;
    }


      public Class B {


        Statement stat = null;      

        Connection con = getconnection();
        stat = con.createStatement();
        stat.execute("create table if not exists Node1(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(255), ip varchar(255), port int, site varchar(255), object_referenece varchar(255), connectivity_status varchar(255))");
        closeConnection(con,stat);



 public  void closeConnection(Connection con, Statement stat) throws 
 SQLException {
    stat.close();
   con.close();

 }
 }
```

I have these two classes, class B is purely for creating table. I need to getConnection method from class A to proceed in class B. When i use this syntax, its asking me to create getconnection method again in this class. Is there any possible way to get method from class A and use it in class B??

Comment: Your code is a bit messy pls review it. Class `B` is missing smth.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rethink the structure of your code. Why would you want an inner class to execute some code you could just put inside a method in the original class A.
However, if for whatever reason you still want class B as an inner class inside calss A, you want to change your syntax.

```
public class A {

    ComboPooledDataSource cpDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            // open a connection
            con = cpDataSource.getConnection();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return con;
    }

    public class B {

        public void createTable() {
            Connection con = getConnection();
            try {
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                stmt.execute("create table if not exists Node1(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(255), ip varchar(255), port int, site varchar(255), object_referenece varchar(255), connectivity_status varchar(255))");
            } catch(SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            closeConnection(con, stmt);
        }

    }

}
```

Note the lowercase **class** at `public class B` since you don't want to define an attribute with the type of `java.lang.Class`. Also note that the code inside class **B** is now wrapped in the method `public void createTable()` because you can't just have codeblocks outside any constructor/method in a java class.
You also want to put the **Statement creation** and the **execution** inside a **try/catch** block.